# Does Freetype support variable fonts?

Tags: c++, freetype

I am building support for Freetype (2.10.1) in my application and I just came across my first serious problem. I opened a font called bahnschrift.ttf that was available in my Windows fonts folder and it seems to support several different styles in a single file. However, Freetype reports only a single face available.
How can I create separate faces for the different font styles in this case? Does Freetype support variable fonts?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

FreeType supports variable fonts since version 2.8.

You probably got to the point of instantiating an `FT_Face` with FreeType. From there, most of the documentation related to OpenType font variations is in the Multiple Masters section of the documentation:
https://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/reference/ft2-multiple_masters.html

To find out which variable axes a font has, you can use:
[FT_Get_MM_Var](https://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/reference/ft2-multiple_masters.html#ft_get_mm_var) on your `FT_Face` which contains the named styles in `FT_MM_Var` structures.

To then set variable font design coordinates, use [FT_Set_Var_Design_Coordinates](https://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/reference/ft2-multiple_masters.html#ft_set_var_design_coordinates) or [FT_Set_Named_Instance](https://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/reference/ft2-multiple_masters.html#ft_set_named_instance) to select a specific named instance.